# How to get average of column with same values on other column after using COUNT?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have the following query:

```
 SELECT *, COUNT(id) AS number_of_orders
 FROM orders
 WHERE MONTH(date) = 5
 GROUP BY item_number, MONTH(date), YEAR(date);
```

And I get the following result:

```
id | item_number  |      date      |  number_of_orders
1  |       4      |   2022-05-15   |       1 
2  |      43      |   2021-05-15   |       2
3  |      43      |   2022-05-15   |       2
4  |      51      |   2021-05-15   |       3
5  |      51      |   2022-05-15   |       3
6  |      51      |   2020-05-15   |       3
```

And I need to get the average number of orders per specific month, per item. In this case it's May (05).

The average per item #4 in months of May would be 1

The average per item #43 in months of  May would be 2

The average per item #51 in months of May would be 1

The raw data is basically the same as the above, not sure if I need to do the `COUNT` step first:

```
id | item_number  |      date      |  
1  |       4      |   2022-05-15   | 
2  |      43      |   2021-05-15   |     
3  |      43      |   2022-05-15   |     
4  |      51      |   2021-05-15   |     
5  |      51      |   2022-05-15   |      
6  |      51      |   2019-08-15   |
```

Comment: Select month(date),  count(id)  and group by month(date).

Comment: (11+32) / 2 isn't 17.5, unless you have more rows of item_numer = 43.

Comment: @JonTout No I need the average per item_number per month what you suggested won't work. Yes you are right my calculation is wrong there. edited. Should be (11+34)/2 = 22.5

Comment: you'll need to post the raw data that is being averaged

Comment: which database are you using, this query should result in an error

Comment: Using MariaDB (I run this query right now so it's working there)

Comment: ok myriadb is horrible as it should be configured in FULL_GROUP_BY_ONLY every thing else results in strange result, i still don't get how you get your numbers from your small rable4

Comment: @nbk thank you, can you explain what is bad in my query that I should avoid? You mean that even though it's working, it's bad and I should use it differently?

Comment: @Pelegrino sure see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=a8aa15e75bda99e89445e1a7b35d1344  but you need to show the result you want from the datable

Comment: @nbk thank you! Stu - sorry I removed some data for the little sample, I will edit the number of orders then to match, and understood, will only select what I need

Answer (score 1):

You can always just use your first query as a subquery and aggregate its results further

```
SELECT y, m, item_number, AVG(number_of_orders) as avg_number_of_orders
FROM (
    SELECT YEAR(date) y, MONTH(date) m, item_number, COUNT(id) AS number_of_orders
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date), item_number
)
GROUP BY y, m, item_number
```

Edited to use proper SQL grouping

Comment: I get a syntax error (MariaDB) and I actually tried something similar with same syntax error

Comment: what error?  I am not familiar with MariaDB

Comment: `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date), item_number LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 7`

Comment: Well that's confusing, it seems to work with your original query which has an invalid grouping, but doesn't work with my outer query that has a valid grouping.

Comment: Maybe you just need an alias.

Comment: @Kurt thank you I still get the same error, I am not sure why because I know it looks OK and I tried using similar sub query but .. same error: 
`Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY y, m, item_number LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 7
`

Comment: Where is that `LIMIT 0, 1000` coming from?  perhaps that is the syntax error?

Comment: I am using MySQL Workbench I think it just automatically adds that limit.

Edit: I just disabled automatic limit, but same error